# Random rsync running in the background on Debian

Tags: debian, security, rsync

I have recently had some lag in my system, when saving a file in `vim`.

I noticed that an `rsync` process was running. It was copying the `~/.openshot_qt` dir (`openshot` is not currently installed on my system). Unfortunately, it was over before I could investigate further.

However, on the system monitor, I could see that an increased disk activity corresponded to an increase network activity.

Without any luck, I tried to find out, if there is a legitimate `rsync` usage on a recent debian system.

Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye), last updated about 1-2 months ago.

### My question is:

**Is there anything that a legitimately uses `rsync` on a recent Debian system?**

Comment: Pew! 

When showing unauthorized use of `rsync` with additional network activity your system is highly suspect of having been hacked... 

Are you able to disconnect the system, and put it under extened analysis?

Comment: @gerhardd. Yes, I can do that. But in the meantime I wanted see if there is some legit reason, why it would happen...